# Writing a recursive JavaScript function returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to learn recursive functions in JS but for some reason the result is *undefined* I want to alert (4,3,2,1,0) respectively.

```
function someFun(number) {
  if (number < 0) {
    return 1;
  } 
  else {
    alert(number = someFun(number - 1))
  }
}
someFun(4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function only has one `return` statement in it. When the `else` path of the `if` statement is taken, nothing is returned.

That said, you really don't *need* a return value because you just want the sequence of numbers printed (in *descending* order):

```
function someFun(number) {
  if (number >= 0) {
    alert(number);
    someFun(number - 1);
  }
}
someFun(4);
```

If you want the numbers printed in *ascending* order, you'd just reverse the order of the `alert()` and the recursive call.